# Partly reusing a function giving the same output for different inputs

Tags: python

I have created a custom function for each button as part of which I am reusing another function.
I want to read from different entry boxes and show values for each stock, but I seem to be getting the same values even though I use different variables. Any idea where I am going wrong?

[image]

```
def definecontract():         #defines the contract that will then be used when placing orders or getting further information
    ticker = tickerentry1.get() 
    exchange = "SMART"
    currency = "USD"
    return ticker, exchange, currency

def gethistoricaldata(barsizesetting, duration):                         #Requests historical data from IBKR on a certain contract   
    ticker, exchange, currency = definecontract()

    tradingstock = Stock(ticker, exchange, currency)
    historicaldata = ib.reqHistoricalData(tradingstock, '', barSizeSetting = barsizesetting ,durationStr=duration ,whatToShow='MIDPOINT', useRTH=True)
    return historicaldata


def runanalysis(tickerfromentryfield):
    ticker = tickerfromentryfield
    exchange = "SMART"
    currency = "USD" 
 
    tradingstock = Stock(tickerfromentryfield, exchange, currency)

    historicaldatashortterm = gethistoricaldata("1 hour", "2 D")
    df_candle_data = util.df(historicaldatashortterm)
    maxvalueshortterm = df_candle_data["high"].max()

    historicaldatalongterm = gethistoricaldata("1 day", "100 D")
    df_candle_data = util.df(historicaldatalongterm)
    maxvaluelongterm = df_candle_data["high"].max()
    return maxvalueshortterm, maxvaluelongterm

def analysis1button():
    ticker1 = tickerentry1.get()
    maxvalueshortterm1, maxvaluelongterm1 = runanalysis(ticker1)
    labelhighvalue1d_ticker1.configure(text=maxvalueshortterm1)
    labelhighvalue_lt_ticker1.configure(text=maxvaluelongterm1)
    
def analysis2button():
    ticker2 = tickerentry2.get()
    maxvalueshortterm2, maxvaluelongterm2 = runanalysis(ticker2)
    labelhighvalue1d_ticker2.configure(text=maxvalueshortterm2)
    labelhighvalue_lt_ticker2.configure(text=maxvaluelongterm2)

def analysis3button():
    ticker3 = tickerentry3.get()
    maxvalueshortterm3, maxvaluelongterm3 = runanalysis(ticker3)
    labelhighvalue1d_ticker3.configure(text=maxvalueshortterm3)
    labelhighvalue_lt_ticker3.configure(text=maxvaluelongterm3)


#definition of buttons
button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Apply', padx=10, pady=5, fg='white', bg='grey', command=analysis1button)
button1.grid(row=1, column=5)

button2 = tk.Button(root, text='Apply', padx=10, pady=5, fg='white', bg='grey', command=analysis2button)
button2.grid(row=2, column=5)

button3 = tk.Button(root, text='Apply', padx=10, pady=5, fg='white', bg='grey', command=analysis3button)
```

Comment: What's in `gethistoricaldata` ? Your `runanalysis` function does nothing with the `tradingstock` variable it creates, so it's no surprise it returns the same result each time. Maybe you need to rewrite `gethistoricaldata` so that it takes `tradingstock` or `ticker` as a parameter?

Comment: I have added gethistoricaldata  to the description now

Comment: `gethistoricaldata` uses the ticker returned by `definecontract`. `definecontract` returns `tickerentry1.get()` every time, so you're always requesting the first ticker's data. Just pass the ticker from the `runanalysis` function to the `gethistoricaldata` function.